# Insert multiple rows using a prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am trying to use the prepared statement query to insert multiple rows in to a table. I need to retrieve 2 values from a second table and insert them along with 3 parameters.

MySQL only sees the sub query as a single value not the 2 retrieved so asks for a further parameter to be added as only four are present.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_permit_daily_sign_off (permit_id, shift, employee_id, sign_off_date, type)
                              VALUES ((SELECT tbl_permit_project.permit_id, tbl_shifts.shift_name FROM tbl_permit_project
                              INNER JOIN tbl_shifts ON tbl_permit_project.project_id = tbl_shifts.project_id
                            WHERE tbl_shifts.end_time <= NOW()), ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iss",  $permit_employee = 0, $today, $type = "auto");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `$type = 'auto'` as a parameter is irregular as far as PHP goes. That variable doesn't matter, just pass `'auto'` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `INSERT ... SELECT` form of insert, not the `INSERT ... VALUES()` form.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_permit_daily_sign_off 
            (permit_id, shift, employee_id, sign_off_date, type)
     SELECT tbl_permit_project.permit_id, tbl_shifts.shift_name  
      FROM tbl_permit_project
INNER JOIN tbl_shifts ON tbl_permit_project.project_id = tbl_shifts.project_id
     WHERE tbl_shifts.end_time <= NOW()), ?, ?, ?)
```

How does this work?

1) you design a SELECT query giving the columns you want to use in your INSERT query. Then you test and troubleshoot it.

2) You put `INSERT INTO tbl (col, col, col...)` right before your SELECT.

Your INSERT chooses the columns `(permit_id, shift, employee_id, sign_off_date, type)` but your SELECT only mentions two of those columns. You need the SELECT to mention all five.